# Create a union function types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to create a union type for arrow functions.

```js
type ItemType = {
  createTime: number;
  totalTime: number;
  text: string;
};

type ObjType = {
  callback: ((item: string) => void) | ((item: ItemType) => void);
}

let obj: ObjType = {
  callback: (item: string) => {
    console.log(item)
  }
}
```

So far it works well.

And then I am going to call the function.

```js
obj.callback('text');
```

It shows an error

```
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string & ItemType'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ItemType'.
```

The type of `callback` became `(item: string & ItemType) => void`.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAksEFsAq5oF4oG8BQU9QGMAnCAQ3iQEsEIAuKAOwFcEAjCIgbl32AHtgpADZUa9Zmw7cAvt2yhIUAPKsAVikUYc+QsKGtSBANb0AFKcrwE9AM7AilBgHMAlFDQA+KADc+lACZuAD5Q5paI9HCIGhBunj5+gTLY2EIQwFB8avQq6qjuWDx4BHoGxmbh1rBWMXFe2jr4BHwMNnxpAHRCfE4WVi7cOtIANNiyKVmqHSVC+oZG2AD0i42NAHoAtFtQYEwZIHxMRIRHbccAFhzQpAz+OyQ2NqFLK6tv1VAA7pSzUDbnfE+UAABpVgVBSE9gXYHM4oAAyarRVDAoA)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thx for your comments. I found out it works on playground but it doesn't on my vscode. The type of `callback` becomes `(item: string & ItemType) => void`. I have no idea what is happening.

Comment: I wish it is just a typo or my mistake.
https://imgur.com/a/owwb4l8

Comment: This is why you have an intersection of both arguments https://catchts.com/react-props#first

Comment: Union of functions is useles in 95% cases

Comment: @captain-yossarian - I had that suspicion -- but only after it didn't work. :-D

Comment: @T.J.Crowder usualy people are getting `Argument of type XXX is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'`. If you see this error in the question it is 90% that OP has union of functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `ObjType` has both possibilities, an object implementing it would have to implment both possibilities to be a valid `ObjType`. If `obj` is going to have only one version of the callback and not the other, I think you need to make `ObjType` generic and accept a type parameter saying which it will be, like this:

```typescript
type ItemType = {
    createTime: number;
    totalTime: number;
};

type ObjType<Item extends string | ItemType> = {
    callback: (item: Item) => void;
};

let obj1: ObjType<ItemType> = {
    callback: (item) => {
        console.log(item);
    },
};
obj1.callback({createTime: 0, totalTime: 0});

let obj2: ObjType<string> = {
    callback: (item) => {
        console.log(item);
    },
};
obj2.callback("example");
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4&ssl=23&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAksEFsAq5oF4oG8BQU9QGMAnCAQ3iQEsEIAuKAOwFcEAjCIgbl32AHtgpADZUa9Zmw7cAvt2yhIUAPKsAVikgAeOIigQAHvAYATAM5RTwIpQYBzKAB9Y8ZKgB8UDDnyFhQ1qQEANb0ABSULvQ6CACUnh4AbnyUxjJyQhDAUHxqAIz0Kuqo2i4aEB5ePHgEfgHBYRGIcWge3j74BHwMpnwZAHRCfLbhLjHcPtIANNiy2DmquX01Qv6BQaGYxGQU1HRQAAyTUPyCIrv0+9Jj2NgZWfMATAVqZZqW1nYVWFW+K3UhUBGTXi33aHS6PX6g2GjVi43wUxm3EeS1qa1CACIDKQEGAMhjrkA)