# Safe way of using key remapped union type of functions

Tags: typescript

Say that I have a union type `Action` discriminated on a single field `@type`, like so:

```js
interface Sum {
    '@type': 'sum'
    a: number
    b: number
}

interface Square {
    '@type': 'square'
    n: number
}

type Action = Sum | Square
```

Then I write a object containing one method for each `Action` using key remapping:

```
const handlers: {[A in Action as A['@type']]: (action: A) => number} = {
    sum: ({a, b}) => a + b,
    square: ({n}) => n ** 2
}
```

Is there a safe way to call one of the handlers passing in the `Action` as an argument? This code should be safe:

```
const runAction = (action: Action) => {
    return handlers[action['@type']](action) // <-- Not valid
}
```

But TypeScript says:

```
Argument of type 'Action' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
  The intersection 'Sum & Square' was reduced to 'never' because property ''@type'' has conflicting types in some constituents.
    Type 'Sum' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

What would be a good way of writing the above function in a safe way without casting to a less strict type?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=1&pln=18&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoFcC2yDeAoZQ5AcgAEwBPABwmIC4SBnLYgouBkLAI2jcO6cefAL548oSLEQpUAR3RwoKfERLlqtBsUYKltfshBDMvKHjF5KNZAEEEYYAHsQyALxosyAD5o9y8QQXRjBkAAs4EAATABtoRgYcAG1bZFA7B2dXOEY7JLJrWgBdIoYACkRHFwZbAEp3AD4jYSgRd1xDZkxynDgAGmRuEXq3JrhkAGpBvs7-CB6QYcajZAAqVeQAJgtA4NCodBB7KtcPCszqjJORptUiZTB0KFcI6LioRiTKrPyNGmISudrsgAPQg5AAHgAtFDkAA5JyhABucBiwCiFiAA)

Comment: `handlers[action['@type']]` produces union of functions which is almost never desired result. Please see my [article](https://catchts.com/react-props) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68966710/how-to-get-concrete-type-from-mapping-variable#answer-68967097) answer for more explanation. TL DR intersection of `Sum & Square` produces `never`

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71177030/create-a-union-function-types-in-typescript#comment125819660_71177030) question/answer is also related

Comment: This kind of correlated union type thing is mentioned in [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) and is only supportable in a non-redundant type safe way in TS4.6+ (which is coming out very soon), due to the PR at  [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) ... but the fix requires refactoring.  It looks something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mqErRm) for your example.  Do you want me to write this up as an answer explaining the situation?

Comment: @jcalz Interesting, I'm definitely going to be looking out for the next typescript release. Thanks for knowledge, it's always difficult to google typescript problems due to the many kind of obscure terms.

Comment: If you wish to add an answer for others who find the question I'll of course accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue here is that the type of `handlers[action['@type']]` and the type of `action` are both [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) (i.e., `((action: Sum) => number) | (action: Square) => number))` and `Sum | Square`), but these values are *correlated* to each other in a way that's not captured by those uncorrelated/independent union types.  The compiler doesn't understand that, for example, you will never be passing a `Square` into `(action: Sum) => number`.  This general issue is the subject of [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).

Note that the compiler does not distribute its [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) across the unions.  Specifically, when analyzing

```
handlers[action['@type']](action)
```

the compiler does not do what a human being might do, and say "okay, `action` is either a `Sum` or a `Square`.  If it's a `Sum`, then `action['@type']` is `"sum"` and so `handlers[action['@type']]` is a `(action: Sum) => number` and so `handlers[action['@type']](action)` is a valid call and results in a `number`. If it's a `Square`, then `action['@type']` is `"square"` and so `handlers[action['@type']]` is a `(action: Square) => number` and so `handlers[action['@type']](action)` is a valid cal and results in a `number`.  In both cases we get a `number`, so the result is a `number`."  Such analysis would require that the compiler look at the line once for each member of the `Action` union.  In this specific situation, that's just twice, but unions can be bigger than two, and the number of cases to analyze grows exponentially in the number of expressions of independent union types.  It's just not feasible for the compiler to potentially analyze a line of code a huge number of times.  The declined  [microsoft/TypeScript#25051](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25051) was a request to allow developers to ask for such extra analysis on an as-needed basis.  But, as I said, it was declined.  So there's no simple fix of the form like "just add `as if switch(action)` to the end of the line".

---

In versions of TypeScript before 4.6, your choices here would either be to just give up on type safety by using [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) or the equivalent:

```
const runAction = (action: Action) => {
    return (handlers[action['@type']] as (action: Action) => number)(action);
}
```

or to write redundant code to force the compiler to perform the kind of multiple-pass analysis I mentioned before:

```
const runAction = (action: Action) => {
    return action['@type'] === "square" ?
        handlers[action['@type']](action) :
        handlers[action['@type']](action);
}
```

Neither of these are great.  The former is my general recommendation if you care more about convenience than safety.  The latter used to be the only way to get type safety, but it doesn't scale well.

---

Starting in TypeScript 4.6, [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) will be released, which gives a way to refactor code with correlated unions to a form that the compiler can verify as safe.  It involves using [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) with so-called "distributive object types".  Here's how it might look for your example:

```
type ActionMap = { [A in Sum | Square as A['@type']]: A }

type Action<K extends keyof ActionMap = keyof ActionMap> =
    { [P in K]: ActionMap[P] & { "@type": P } }[K]

const runAction = <K extends keyof ActionMap>(action: Action<K>) => {
    return handlers[action['@type']](action)
}
```

First we set up an `ActionMap` type which is a simple mapping from `A['@type']` as keys to the corresponding action type.  It looks like `{sum: Sum; square: Square}`.

Then we define `Action` not as a plain union, but as a generic `Action<K>` type that takes a subtype of `"sum" | "square"` and produces the corresponding action type.  This is the "distributive object type" where `Action<K>` will be a union if `K` is a union.  There's a [default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults), so just writing `Action` produces the same union type from your code.  Note that there's a little twist here, which is that we are explicitly telling the compiler that, generically, for each union member `P` in `K`, `Action<K>` will have a `"@type"` property of type `P`.  This is redundant information, but it helps the compiler see the correlation better.

Finally, `runAction()` is now a generic function in `K`, where `action` is of type `Action<K>`.  And now, `handlers[action['@type']](action)` is seen as type safe without having to be written multiple times.  The downside is that the refactoring is not obvious, but this is about as good as it gets in terms of type safety and scalability.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.0-dev.20220215#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBBKUICcAuSDeAUEsUgJbDZYBmCyAygK5j5ElsDkAAtgJ4wTsAXEnZQm7Vm2IhhwJgCMskqfNkKlbAL4Fl5SphqIkdAI4MQmZISkkuvfkJFQzFgcrbA1YRZmXbl9sgo8NikAPbASAC8xkxIAD7GLpY6bPARULgAFiDAACYANlhQwnhIANooZJHBoRFIIFCo5XZ8AgC67cIAFAh1nqgAlNEAfEhy3lhImtEsNsRiYD1lIAA0SPLTw1FjIEgA1Bur7iTO5pbL41ujVwBUt0gATH6pJOnAmUiYDMC14ZExXohf7CP4RbZjazzSzYBiYSLdHL5IqYKDlPr-FrcNrsToNJpA-qg4Hgm4THyDQn-QYAbhe-lAkFgtCQACUIHkfnlcrgocQ9NQWYxmHypK0HMJROITtIvD4ZRs5RoSP42AKDELklYFeKBJKzq4JPNxkrfFpXsRAqgSQDYsxEqZzhALUh3p8kYViqUKlVyNb+vjmrrcV0kFSIqCIeN1JhprNRWxFpc1htrjsGgcjgqDRcw2VIpoo5F7k8Xso3bhvr8bbNwwMwcAowmSDC4ZEMREsYFcdEojEAEQ5iD9pAAfgVbA9KLRHeAXZxnTrw0EE5IU+K6Jt84ci9ntPpOgIjOgcCM7MM2DCscIugogqMwrm8372P4-f10uNMmjkzN81UP7yuat76IY9Bak+NgvoE75OFqRrzAM5LKsQqokFaDYALIgDA8Y+tUdoJEkTqBig24dKGVRoZabT+v8AA8ADSSAQAAHpQ+RNAA1hAPBhFQdERNhuExDxfECVhOFjFECplOUAAKBGMZRNrCQp7RIAAZPgSDQW0sGKTMmjlMpLoVkg66ot6JkEWJ-GCcAwmhnWxL9ExIxFjGcYxM2CxMMm6ybIWNx7Ic8jHMaQ6XAWRZICWzzAWkGSVj8DazExLHsRAnFIHZEmqVJLkOe5TYKq28IWbknqopu-TkSGS5lpoQA)